# Unable to close Modal due to Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I run the following code, when I click on the Current Children option of the dropdown menu, the corresponding Modal displays on my screen but then I am unable to close it as I get the following error at `

```
spanModal.onclick = function()
```

The error is:

```
userTemplate.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (userTemplate.js:25)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.js:5206)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.2.1.js:5014)
```

Why do I get this error?

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Children <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" class="menu" id="currentChildren">Current Children</a></li>
                        <li>
                    </ul>  
                </li>
           </ul>
     </div>

<div id="currentChildrenModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" id="currentChildrenModalSpan">&times;</span>
      <p>List of all currently enrolled children. Include option to filter by group.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".menu").on("click", function()
{
    var modalFireButton;
    var modalName;
    var spanModal;
    var span;
    //get Id of button cliced
    modalFireButton = $(this).attr('id');

    //set variable for corresponding modal 
    modalName = (modalFireButton + "Modal");

    modalName = document.getElementById(modalName);
    span = (modalName + "Span");

    spanModal = document.getElementById(span)

    // spanModal = document.getElementById(spanModal);   

    modalName.style.display='block';

    spanModal.onclick = function()
        {
            modalName.style.display = "none";
        }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`span = (modalName + "Span");`

to

`span = (modalName.id + "Span");`

modalName refers to `<div id="currentChildrenModal" class="modal">` and to get `currentChildrenModal` you need to use `modalName.id` and append `Span` to get handle to span `<span class="close" id="currentChildrenModalSpan">&times;</span>`

Answer (score 1):

Your modalName is supposed to be a string, but the following line makes it an element:

```
modalName = document.getElementById(modalName);
```

That's why your span variable is not a correct string to get the element. You can't attach onclick to the spanModal element if it can't be found. One good thing to try is to name your variables so that you can easily find out what they mean. Try the following:

```
$(".menu").on("click", function()
{
    var modalFireButton;
    var modalName;
    var modalElm;
    var spanModal;
    var spanName;

    modalFireButton = $(this).attr('id');

    //set variable for corresponding modal 
    modalName = (modalFireButton + "Modal");
    spanName = (modalName + "Span");

    modalElm = document.getElementById(modalName);

    spanModal = document.getElementById(spanName)


    modalElm.style.display='block';

    spanModal.onclick = function()
    {
        modalElm.style.display = "none";
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code is wrong:

```
modalName = document.getElementById(modalName);
span = (modalName + "Span");

spanModal = document.getElementById(span)
```

As you are trying to concatenate an HTMLElement with a string.

Comment: That's correct. In your case, it seems like you want the span name to be something like "modal.id + "Span"